# Can't save my file in a txt file

Tags: python

```
def highscore():
    var = input("Please enter your nickname ")
    ### And then i want this to be saved within the txt file on my desktop. 
    self.highscoreList.sort() #Sorterar listan man har med highscores (behövs ju inte om den redan är sorterad)
    if playerScore > self.highscoreList[0]: #Om spelarens poäng högre än lägsta highscore
        self.highscoreList[0] = playerScore #Byt ut det lägsta mot spelarens
            #Nånting sånt här iallafall...
        file = read("/Volumes/me SSD/Users/me/Desktop/Python/highscore.txt", "w")
        for highscore in self.highscoreList: #Sen skriva till fil!
            file.write(highscore) #Skriver highscores till filen, en för varje rad
            file.write("hej") #I have even tried to just have \n
    file.close()
```

I have made a game (minesweaper) in python 3.5.2 and when the player has played the game, I want him/her to enter his/her nickname so it will save the highscore in a (txt) file on the desktop.

I tried to do this, but it won't save anything in the txt file. And also the player doesn't get the input to write down his/her nickname.

I tried to have the file.close() in or without the loop, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you mean to `open()` the file instead of `read()`? Also file closing is outside the `if` which may cause problem if the condition in `if` returns false

Comment: The indentation's off

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, the canonical way to write to a file is e.g.,

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    print("my output", file=output_file)
```

Note that I opened the file inside an `with` block, so that it is automatically closed, and that I printed to the file by supplying a keyword argument `file` to Python 3's `print` function.

You can use the extended `print` function in Python 2 by importing it first,

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and then calling `print` as usual.

Comment: Python 2 also supports this

Comment: No, it doesn't, print isn't a function in Python 2, it's a keyword. You can import the print function from future etc though

Comment: I thougt you used `write` not print. Sorry, I'm still half-awake.

Comment: What shall I remove in my code to replace this one with?

Comment: @soetirl figure it out yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
use this

       try:
        fil = open("/Volumes/Melinas SSD/Users/Melina/Desktop/Python/melinas.txt", "w")
    except:
        print('the file cannot be opened')

for highscore in self.highscoreList: 


print('hello')
            file.write(highscore)
            file.write("hej")
```

Comment: change to something else = open("/Volumes/me SSD/Users/me/Desktop/Python/highscore.txt", "w")

file is reserved keyword

Comment: do one thing right click on your file and see the properties and check the file path and replace it here.

And change the 'w' to 'a'

Comment: beacuse I think I have write down the User/me blabla correct? please se the link https://www.pixeltopic.com/image/ynkgazaakrnvglu/

what does 'a' mean?

Comment: can you do one thing? create a new file in your directory where this file is and only give the file name and not the full path like

open("highscore.txt", "a") and then check

Comment: Ofc, but nothing: https://www.pixeltopic.com/image/mpwtkjppwnccemn/ i tried also "w", "r", "a"

Comment: put print(highscore) before fil.write and give the ouput here

Comment: this is the whole code, (sorry is in written in swedish maybe you understand it still :)   maybe it it placed wrong the def of highscore? https://gist.github.com
and
https://www.pixeltopic.com/image/sqntpubhmjrtc/ here is when write print(highscore) even tried print(melina)

Comment: see you havent change the name from 'file' to 'fil' where you are opening the file. change it.

Comment: i have edited my answer. put that code inplace of the old one and see if you are getting any error or not

Comment: https://www.pixeltopic.com/image/hzpffyjpdxwwhpz/.. just thinking about the print(melina) , shall it be in a string? or melina.txt? or just highscore?  because it won't print anything

Comment: did you put the code and saw what comes up? like file cant be opened or not

Comment: put this code and see if the hello is getting printed or not

Comment: So the whole code is now https://gist.github.com/melyhna/44d4902240a2f6fde118710b44cc60c7 and a screen shot; https://www.pixeltopic.com/image/lqmyvstsykorpmf/ no wrong message, no print.. can it be wrong because it's placed wrong in the code? or is it something else who missing?

Comment: ok so hello is not getting printed. that means there is a problem with self.highscoreList 

Check it properly as the loop is getting blank. thus nothing is getting in the file

Answer (score 1):

Before you can read or write a file, you have to open it using Python's built-in `open()` function. This function creates a file object, which would be utilized to call other support methods associated with it. here is the syntax
`file object = open(file_name [, access_mode][, buffering])`

```
file = open("/Volumes/me SSD/Users/me/Desktop/Python/highscore.txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to Write content in File**

Use `open()` method to write content in file, not read() and read() is not built-in method.

**Demo:**

```
>>> fp = open("mytest.txt", "w")
>>> fp.write("I am Python Developer.")
>>> fp.write("\nI Love Coding.")
>>> fp.close()
```

**Note**:

Do not use variable name which are reserved in Python i.e. Keyword.
A `file` is built-in keyword.

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
```

Where you define `playerScore` variable?

Comment: That's correct one. Also context manager could be used so
    with open(path_to_file) as f:
        f.write('Something')

Comment: I tried to change all this file to fil, and read to open, but it wont print :'(

Comment: @soetirl: need you code. can you share with us again?

Comment: @VivekSable https://www.pixeltopic.com/image/wmyjxacgnfzqnbl/  hoope is okej to send you a picture instead of the code? because stock have limit of characters ^^

Comment: @soetirl: email me, for email ID see my Stackover Profile.